# Challenge with codes stemming from an issue regarding the "Hashable" property

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, jinja2

We are attempting to refactor and modify a Python program such that it is able to take a user-defined JSON file, parse that file, and then execute a workflow based on the options that they user wants and had defined in the JSON. So basically, the user will have to specify a dictionary in JSON, and when this JSON file is parsed by the Python program, we obtain a python dictionary which we then pass in as an argument into a class that we instantiate in a top level module. To sum this up, the JSON dictionary defined by the user will eventually be added into the instance namespace when the python program is running.

Implementing the context managers to parse the JSON inputs was not a problem for us. However, we have a requirement that we be able to use the JSON dictionary (which gets subsequently added into the instance namespace) and [generate multiple lines from a Jinja2 template file using looping within a template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#list-of-control-structures). We attempted to use this line for one of the key-value pairs in the JSON:

```
"extra_scripts" : [["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua",
                    "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua"]]
```

and this is sitting in a large dictionary object, let's call it `option_space_dict` and for simplicity in this example, it has only 4 key-value pairs (assume that `"extra_scripts"` is `'key4'` here), although for our program, it is much larger:

```
option_space_dict = {
                     'key1' : ['value1'],
                     'key2' : ['value2'],
                     'key3' : ['value3A', 'value3B', 'value3C'],
                     'key4' : [['value4A', 'value4B']]
                    }
```

which is the parsed by this line:

```
import itertools

option_space = [ dict(itertools.izip(option_space_dict, opt)) for opt in itertools.product(*option_space_dict.itervalues()) ]
```

to get the `option_space` which essentially differs from `option_space_dict` in that it is something like:

```
[
 { 'key1' : 'value1',
   'key2' : 'value2',
   'key3' : 'value3A'
   'key4' : ['value4A', 'value4B'] },

 { 'key1' : 'value1',
   'key2' : 'value2',
   'key3' : 'value3B'
   'key4' : ['value4A', 'value4B'] },

 { 'key1' : 'value1',
   'key2' : 'value2',
   'key3' : 'value3C'
   'key4' : ['value4A', 'value4B'] }
]
```

So the `option_space` we generate serves us well for what we want to do with the jinja2 templating. However, in order to get this, the `key4` key that we added to `option_space_dict` caused an issue somewhere else in the program which did:

```
# ignore self.option as it is not relevant to the issue here
def getOptionCompack(self) :
return [ (k, v) for k, v in self.option.iteritems() if set([v]) != set(self.option_space_dict[k])]
```

I get the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` stemming from the fact that the value of `key4` contains a nested list structure, which is 'unhashable'.

So we kind of hit a barrier. Does anyone have a suggestion on how we could overcome this; being able to specify our JSON files in that way to do what we'd want with Jinja2 while still being able to parse the data structures out in the same format?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Define a way to turn the list into a string and use those for comparison/hashing? E.g., `''.join(sorted(my_list))`?

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize your *key* data structures to use hashable types after they have parsed from JSON.

Since `key4` is a list, you have two options:

1. Convert it to a tuple where order is significant. E.g.,

   ```
   key = tuple(key)
   ```
2. Convert it to a [frozenset](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) where order is insignificant. E.g.,

   ```
   key = frozenset(key)
   ```

If a key can contain a dictionary, then you'll have two additional options:

1. Convert it to either a sorted tuple or frozenset of its item tuples. E.g.,

   ```
   key = tuple(sorted(key.iteritems())) # Use key.items() for Python 3.
   # OR
   key = frozenset(key.iteritems()) # Use key.items() for Python 3.
   ```
2. Convert it to a third-party [frozendict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/frozendict/0.4) (Python 3 compatible version [here](https://github.com/jaraco/python-frozendict)). E.g.,

   ```
   import frozendict
   key = frozendict.frozendict(key)
   ```

Depending on how simple or complex your keys are, you may have to apply the transformation recursively.

Since your keys come directly from JSON, you can check for the native types directly:

```
if isinstance(key, list):
    # Freeze list.
elif isinstance(key, dict):
    # Freeze dict.
```

If you want to support the generic types, you can do something similar to:

```
import collections
if isinstance(key, collections.Sequence) and not isinstance(key, basestring): # Use str for Python 2.
    # NOTE: Make sure to exclude basestring because it meets the requirements for a Sequence (of characters).
    # Freeze list.
elif isinstance(key, collections.Mapping):
    # Freeze dict.
```

Here is a full example:

```
def getOptionCompack(self):
    results = []
    for k, v in self.option.iteritems():
        k = self.freeze_key(k)
        if set([v]) != set(self.option_space_dict[k]):
            results.append((k, v))
    return results

def freeze_key(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, list):
        return frozenset(self.freeze_key(subv) for subv in key)
    # If dictionaries need to be supported, uncomment this.
    #elif isinstance(key, dict):
    #    return frozendict((subk, self.freeze_key(subv)) for subk, subv in key.iteritems())
    return key
```

Where `self.option_space_dict` already had its keys converted using `self.freeze_key()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, when I tried implementing what you showed in the full example, I still ran into the exact same error, that there is the `unhashable` `list` type. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: @AKKO Can you edit your question to include what line the error occurs on, and what key-value pair from `self.options` fails?

Comment: Its actually key-value pairs such as the one I have already included in my question: `"extra_scripts" : [["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua",
                    "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua"]]` that fail because the nested list is non hashable.

Comment: Its been a while back and I apologize for the late reply, but it was on line `if set([v]) != set(self.option_space_dict[k]):` if I remember correctly. Basically,  `self.option_space_dict[k]` will get the value `[["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua", "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua"]]` that is a nested list, but `set()` cannot work directly on this nested list and it throws that `TypeError` error.

Comment: We have figured out the solution for this and I will post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

We have managed to figure out the solution to this problem. The main gist of our solution lies in that we implemented a Helper Function that assists us to actually convert a list into a tuple. Basically, going back to my question, remember we had this list: `[["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua", "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua"]]`?
With our original `getOptionCompack(self)` method, and the way we were invoking it, what happened was that we directly tried to convert the list to a set with the statement

```
return [ (k, v) for k, v in self.option.iteritems() if set([v]) != set(self.option_space_dict[k])]
```

where `set(self.option_space_dict[k])` and iterating over `k` would mean we will hit the dictionary key-value pair that would give us one instance of doing `set([["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua", "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua"]])`
which was the cause of the error. This is because a list object is not hashable and `set()` would actually hash over each element within the outer list that is fed to it, and the element in this case is an inner list. Try doing `set([[2]])` and you will see what I mean.

So we figured that the workaround would be to define a Helper function that would accept a list object, or any iterable object for that matter, and test whether each element in it is a list or not. If the element was not a list, it would not do any change to its object type, if it was (and that which would be a nested list), then the Helper function would convert that nested list to a tuple object instead, and in doing that iteratively, it actually constructs a set object that it returns to itself. The definition of the function is:

```
# Helper function to build a set
def Set(iterable) :
  return { tuple(v) if isinstance(v, list) else v for v in iterable }
```

and so a call that invoked `Set()` would be in our example:

```
Set([["Altera/AlteraCommon.lua", "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua"]])
```

and the object that it returns to itself would be:

```
{("Altera/AlteraCommon.lua", "Altera/StratixIV/EP4SGX70HF35C2.lua")}
```

The inner nested list gets converted to a tuple, which is an object type that fits within a set object, as denoted by the `{}` that encloses the tuple. That's why it can work now, that the set can be formed.

We proceeded to redefine out original method to use our own `Set()` function:

```
def getOptionCompack(self) :
  return [ (k, v) for k, v in self.option.iteritems() if Set([v]) != Set(self.option_space_dict[k]) ]
```

and now we no longer have the `TypeError`, and solved the problem. Seems like a lot of trouble just to do this, but the reason why we went through all this was so as to have an objective means of comparing two objects by sort of "normalizing" them to be the same object type, a set, in order to perform some other action later on as part of our source code.